# Visual Basic - find occurrence of a value in an array

Tags: arrays, vba

As the title says, i need to find how many times my value will occur in my array. In this case I am looking for how many times the integer 0 occurs and for it to return the total amount of 0s. Anyone know what the syntax is for it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please note that this is note a code writing 
 or homework completing service. But rather for assisting people with errors in their code or finding a solution to a certain part of their code. However, what you are asked is fairly straightforward if you know how to work with arrays. Also  See my answer below. Enjoy stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the `SomeArray` with the `Array` you has assigned with you other code.

```
Sub CountIntInArray()

    Dim SomeArray As Variant

    Dim ArrayPos As Long
    Dim Num0s As Long
    Num0s = 0

    'Assuming you only have one level in the array
    'otherwsie you will need to check each level as well
    'See the help file on Ubound for more info
    For ArrayPos = 0 To UBound(SomeArray)

        If SomeArray(ArrayPos) = 0 Then
            Num0s t = Num0s + 1
        End If

        'If you want to ignore the decimals then you can use
        If Int(SomeArray(ArrayPos)) = 0 Then
            Num0s t = Num0s + 1
        End If

    Next ArrayPos

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i was looking around for it however most of what i found was finding the quantity of all same values in an array.